# Parse installation deleteInBackground()

Tags: swift, parse-platform

and I am using installations for push notifications.

I am trying use a func to delete all channels on a installation, without using removeObject, since then the apps bugs out while being online since it will be storing addUniqueobject and removeObject without saving in the background. I tried using.

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
               currentInstallation.deleteInBackground()
```

but it doesn't remove the channels from the installation. Does anyone know how to remove all channels from a parse installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the channels on the current installation channel property, then save the installation object.

I don't remember the name of the property exactly but it's probably something like:

```
PFInstallation.currentInstallation.channels = [""]
PFInstallation.currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot, but you couldn't use nil. It worked with [""]